# How to fix ‘My request is executed twice’ with volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on an Android mobile application with a client / server type architecture. In summary, the application connects to a server to credit or debit the user account.
I use Android Volley to make connections with the server. The first problem states the following:

** For some reason, when I run a mobile client request to debit an account, the request is made twice, which results in the account being debited twice.

After thinking, I thought that this is probably due to the interface RetryPolicy volleyball. I set the number of tententives to 0 which causes the next problem.

** When I launch the request, after a few moments, the mobile client receives an error (the server has not responded) but the action has been done on the server (the account has been debited)

How to solve the problem? The balance of a user must be debited or credited once for the same request regardless of the connection status.

Comment: If you don't show us the code, we have no way of knowing what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `setRetryPolicy` in `Volley`. DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES means request will retry 1 time if there are some issues, So total it will execute 2 times in that case.

So change `DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES` to `0` in `setRetryPolicy`

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                0, //Change DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES to 0 for no retry
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

0 Means no retry

Comment: yes it is this code that I use but it does not work. In the worst case, the user's balance is debited twice

Comment: are you using `DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES`?

Comment: Chirag Savsani YES

Comment: Then change it to `0`, Because DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES  will retry 1 time if there is any issue or too slow network. So total it will execute 2 times in that case. So change it to 0 for no retry.

Comment: Yas i set it to 0. ** When I launch the request, after a few moments, the mobile client receives an error (the server has not responded) but the action has been done on the server (the account has been debited)

Comment: Yes so your 1 issue is solved. Now account will debited 1 time only instead of 2 time. And for the `the server has not responded`, there might be issue from the server side.

Comment: Chirag Savsani  Thank